# Dynamic template names

Tags: go

I'm passing a struct to a nested template and trying to render a different template based on a field in that struct.

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    allContent := getContent()

    response := []struct {
        Title   string
        Content []Content
        Form    string
    }{
        {"BIG TITLE, allContent.bigContent, "big_form"},
        {"SMALL TITLE, allContent.smallContent, "small_form"},
    }

    t, err := template.ParseFiles("content.html", "big_form.html", "small_form.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to parse template: %v", err)
    }
    if err := t.Execute(w, response); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to execute template: %v", err)
    }
}
```

and the template:

```
{{range .}} {{$form := .Form}}
<h1 class="blocks-header inlined">{{.Title}}</h1>
{{range .Content}}
<p>{{.Something}}</p>
{{template $form .}}
{{end}} {{end}}
```

The `$form` variable renders as a string when used on it's own (`<p>{{$form}}</p>`) but when used as the template name I get the error:  `unexpected "$form" in template clause`

How can I pass the template name in a way the template clause will understand?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28831138/230340).

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't find that in my searching.